# Adjective for a person saying "I told you so"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

How might you describe someone who takes an enjoyment in saying "I told you so" after the fact?

Let's say a friend gives you advice on a matter and you decide to go against it. Their advice turned out to be correct and the person consequently makes it a point to say "I told you so; you should have tried the lobster instead" or "you should have brought an umbrella; told you so" and so on. How could you describe this penchant toward bringing up what SHOULD have been done?

I brainstormed a few but feel they don't entirely capture what I'm looking for:

> sticking it to you, know-it-all-ism, woulda-coulda-shoulda, smarty-pants, self-righteous

Comment: Why do none of the brainstorming expressions in your question work? You've provided them, but you haven't said what's *wrong* with them—or the type of thing you're trying to say instead.

Comment: search "cacoethes carpendi"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I think *know-it-all* as in "*know-it-all* person" is the best answer, but given that you've taken it off the table, how about **judgmental**? From Lexico:

> **[judgmental](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/judgmental)**: Having or displaying an excessively critical point of view, e.g., *I don't like to sound **judgmental**, but it was a big mistake*

Answer (score 1):

The very old term is a ***Scold***. One who always criticizes.

Here the noun Scold is an old, original, use of the verb scold. One who used to be called a scold was called that because they were always scolding people. Now it is only seen as the verb to scold. This means to verbally reprimand another in hardly constructive ways. This amount to saying "I told you so." One may add this on occasion but if it is all they ever have to say then they can be called out with such a name.

It has become a regular verb but began as a description for one who did the Scolding.

> **mid-12c.**, "person of ribald speech," later "person fond of abusive language" (c. 1300), especially a shrewish woman [Johnson defines it as "A clamourous, rude, mean, low, foul-mouthed woman"], from Old Norse skald "poet" (see skald). The sense evolution might reflect the fact that Germanic poets (like their Celtic counterparts) were famously feared for their ability to lampoon and mock (as in skaldskapr "poetry," also, in Icelandic law books, "libel in verse").
>
> **late 14c.**, "be abusive or quarrelsome," from scold (n.).

Related: Scolded; scolding.  Thanks to etymonline

Comment: Can you please provide more information with this suggestion? Maybe some example usages and links to official definitions?

Comment: Here the noun *Scold* is an old, original, use of the verb scold. One who used to be called a scold was called that because they were always scolding people. Now it is only seen as the verb to scold. This means to verbally reprimand another in hardly constructive ways. This amount to saying "I told you so." One may add this on occasion but if it is all they ever have to say then they can be called out with such a name.

Comment: I added your comment to the answer and put in some styling also

Comment: @Hank; Thank you! I should have done the same.